# Global constructor gone wrong after inline assembly

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, riscv

I'm having an issue that I cannot explain.

I have a global constructor that sets TP:

```
void init_threads()
{
    register long tp asm("tp");
    asm volatile("mv %0, %1" : "=r"(tp) : "r"(&main_thread));
    asm volatile("ret");
}

_ZN11microthread12init_threadsEv():
   27e8c:       000d27b7                lui     a5,0xd2
   27e90:       ba878793                addi    a5,a5,-1112 # d1ba8 <_ZN11microthreadL11main_threadE>
   27e94:       00078213                mv      tp,a5
   27e98:       00008067                ret
```

It's probably not the best way to do it, so feel free to suggest an improvement.

Unfortunately, it breaks my program, as register a5 is being used directly after this constructor call. I'm not sure how to change a5 to something else because it keeps picking it again and again. Not to mention, why does this happen? If I remove the naked attribute it still won't restore the value. Should it?

The init array loop looks like this:

```
│   0x807e8 <__libc_init_array+68>  jalr    a5                                                                       │
│   0x807ec <__libc_init_array+72>  bne     s2,s1,0x807dc <__libc_init_array+56>                                     │
│   0x807f0 <__libc_init_array+76>  lui     s0,0xc0                                                                  │
│   0x807f4 <__libc_init_array+80>  lui     s2,0xc0                                                                  │
│   0x807f8 <__libc_init_array+84>  addi    a5,s0,896                                                                │
│   0x807fc <__libc_init_array+88>  addi    s2,s2,952                                                                │
│   0x80800 <__libc_init_array+92>  sub     s2,s2,a5                                                                 │
│   0x80804 <__libc_init_array+96>  srai    s2,s2,0x3                                                                │
│   0x80808 <__libc_init_array+100> beqz    s2,0x80828 <__libc_init_array+132>                                       │
│   0x8080c <__libc_init_array+104> addi    s0,s0,896                                                                │
│   0x80810 <__libc_init_array+108> li      s1,0                                                                     │
│   0x80814 <__libc_init_array+112> ld      a5,0(s0)                                                                 │
│   0x80818 <__libc_init_array+116> addi    s1,s1,1                                                                  │
│   0x8081c <__libc_init_array+120> addi    s0,s0,8                                                                  │
│  >0x80820 <__libc_init_array+124> jalr    a5                                                                       │
```

The first jump to a5 is init_threads, while the second is whatever constructor comes next. Expectedly, a5 has a bogus value after returning from init_threads.

Thanks!

Comment: `asm volatile("ret");` is *extremely* broken.  You can't just `ret` in the middle of an arbitrary C++ function.  You can't even safely jump out of an `asm` statement without `asm goto`, and there's no way to tell the compiler you want it to run the epilogue (restore any call-preserved regs and restore the stack poitner) before an asm statement.  Also, `__attribute__((naked))` doesn't support Extended asm statements, only Basic.  (But GCC will still compile the function, just making potentially broken asm.)

Comment: Why not write the function by hand, with `la tp, main_thread` / `ret`?

Comment: Also, does this init function have a custom calling convention or something?  Normally `a5` is call-clobbered.  Yeah, looks normal to me; the next use of `a5` follows a `ld      a5,0(s0)` which overwrites it without any dependency on the old value.  And before that an `addi    a5,s0,896` also uses it as a temporary.

Comment: Inline assembly is very compiler-specific, so it would be better to inclide compiler name explicitely (I assume that it is GCC).

Comment: Thank you, I ended up implementing it as a global assembly function, and now everything works well. I'm not sure why the compiler was not taking care of a5, but making the constructor a normal function made the behavior correct again.

Comment: @gonzo possibly because the function is naked and you returned with `asm volatile("ret")`?

Comment: The asm output you show in the question looks like an optimized build.  If you made a debug build, likely your `asm("ret")` would return with the stack pointer pointing to the wrong place, since `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is the default at `-O0`.  It's very likely not anything to do with `a5`, since as I pointed out, the caller doesn't depend on a5 being preserved by this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
__attribute__((constructor, used))
static void init_threads()
{
    microthread_set_tp(&main_thread);
}

asm(".section .text\n"
".global microthread_set_tp\n"
".type microthread_set_tp, @function\n"
"microthread_set_tp:\n"
"  mv tp, a0\n"
"  ret\n");
```

I'm posting this to show how I solved it, but to also make people aware of another issue I had: The function would not appear no matter how hard I tried, and the problem turned out to be that the current section was not .text. After making sure the correct section is selected, everything worked as expected. I believe you can have some pretty random issues if you forget to set the section!

Comment: Why not `asm volatile("mv tp, %0" :: "r"(&main_thread));` (intentionally omitting a `: "tp"` clobber) *without* an `asm("ret")`?  If this function only exists to modify a global(?) register.  Or even put an `la` inside the asm statement and use a constraint that expands to the asm symbol name, instead of asking for the value already in a register.  https://godbolt.org/z/13M63Mxej shows `asm volatile("la tp, %0" :: "i"(&main_thread));` compiling to `la tp, main_thread`.

Comment: That's what I had originally however the function kept restoring TP to the original value before exiting the function. I'm pretty sure that's the exact incantation I had with LTO enabled.

Comment: Even without declaring a clobber on `tp` or mentioning it as an output?  (And that's why you added an `asm("ret")` to skip the compiler's epilogue and break everything?)  Oh well, if this only runs once on startup, and an extra couple instructions of code-size aren't an issue, a stand-alone function definitely won't let the compiler know that `tp` is being modified.